# Obtaining the number of Days it takes to reach the desired amount

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I currently have a data frame which contains Name of Station, Date of Rainfall, Amount of Rainfall (Example attached) I am interested in exploring the number of days (and/or months) it takes each Station to reach a particular amount of rainfall.
For example:

[image]

Is it possible to obtain an output like the one above based on a dataset like the example one?
My initial thought process is to filter each station individually, join to a calendar dataframe which extracts the min and max from that range, count the days between them and use a case_when to categorize them. This approach seems a bit convoluted and would appreciate any guidance as to what would be a better approach.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Example Dataset:

```
Example <- structure(list(Name.Station = c("Station A", "Station A", "Station A", 
                                        "Station A", "Station A", "Station B", "Station B", "Station B", 
                                        "Station C", "Station C", "Station C", "Station C"), Rainfall.Date = c("7/10/2020", 
                                                                                                               "8/12/2020", "8/01/2021", "25/06/2021", "26/10/2021", "7/01/2020", 
                                                                                                               "22/01/2020", "5/02/2020", "5/09/2020", "5/10/2020", "5/11/2020", 
                                                                                                               "5/12/2020"), Rainfall.Amount = c(210, 210, 208.47, 208.16, 203.67, 
                                                                                                                                                 227.49, 225, 222.54, 250, 250, 246.18, 245.15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -12L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Example %>%
  group_by(Name.Station) %>%
  mutate(Rainfall.Date = as.Date(Rainfall.Date, "%d/%m/%Y"),
         days = cumsum(c(1, diff(Rainfall.Date))),
         crainfall = cumsum(Rainfall.Amount),
         fi = (findInterval(crainfall, seq(0, 1000, 200)) -1) * 200) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Name.Station, names_from = fi, values_from = days, names_glue = {"days_to_{fi}_mm"}, values_fn = min)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   Name.Station [3]
  Name.Station days_to_200_mm days_to_400_mm days_to_600_mm days_to_800_mm days_to_1000_mm
  <chr>                 <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Station A                 1             63             94            262             385
2 Station B                 1             16             30             NA              NA
3 Station C                 1             31             62             92              NA
```

Comment: This makes a ton of sense, thanks man! Just to understand some blurry concepts in fi = {x <- seq(0, 500000, 25000); x[findInterval(crainfall, x)]}) X creates the sequence of intervals based on (x,y, by interval) and then x[findInterval(crainfall, x)]} verifies if the column crainfall meets the requirement of the by interval right? Is there a way to turn the days = cumsum(c(1, diff(Donation.Date))) into months? Would the logic be adding %m in the diff?

Comment: No, it's just a quick way of returning the lower bound of the interval rather than the interval number.  Using the day values in `days_to_400_mm`, what would the conversion to months look like?  I'm not sure of your expected output.

Comment: I ask about the month to understand the approach of cumsum within a date range in different intervals and explore alternatives such as month/year etc. because I am getting an error running the whole data set and I think it might be because of the large number of dates "Values from `days` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols."

Comment: That warning is due to the cases not being uniquely identified in the pivot from long to wide.  Sorry, didn't think this through as in your example data each record contains enough cumulative rainfall to shift it into the next interval which is obviously not the case in your real data.  In that case, would you want the earliest day that the threshold is reached?

Comment: Not a problem at all, def cleared a lot of questions! I was giving it some thought on it and yeah its def on the pivot phase, the earliest day that is reached would work on the real data case. Interested to see the approach for that

Comment: Please see the edit - the fix is simple, you just need to use the `values_fn` argument to take the minimum.  I also changed the calculation of `fi` to hopefully something less opaque.

Comment: damn quite an easy fix, thanks for that! The new fi approach makes total sense, have a great day

Answer (score 4):

`by` station you could calculate the `cumsum` of rainfall greater than the threshold in *mm*. Then calculate the `length` of the `seq`uence of days from start date to the date which is maximum in the cumsum.

First of all, though, your dates should be formatted properly.

```
Example <- transform(Example, Rainfall.Date=as.Date(Rainfall.Date, '%d/%m/%Y'))

do.call(rbind, by(Example, Example$Name.Station, \(x) {
  f <- \(mm, x.=x) {
    mx <- which.max(cumsum(x.$Rainfall.Amount) > mm)
    length(do.call(seq.Date, c(as.list(range(x.$Rainfall.Date[1:mx])), 1)))
  }
  ds <- seq.int(200, 1e3, 200)  ## sequence of 200, 400, ... , 1000mm
  r <- t(vapply(ds, f, 0))
  data.frame(Name.Station=el(x$Name.Station), `colnames<-`(r, paste0('d_', ds)))
}))
#           Name.Station d_200 d_400 d_600 d_800 d_1000
# Station A    Station A     1    63    94   262    385
# Station B    Station B     1    16    30     1      1
# Station C    Station C     1    31    62    92      1
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ran it with my list adding additional values and got "Error in seq.int() : too many arguments". I am trying to troubleshoot it but the code is above my level hahaha Sadly I am mostly used to tidyverse approaches :( Do you think it would be easier if it was just Name.Station and two columns MM and Days so it ends up being like a type of pivot longer type of approach?

Comment: @Raul Your dates have to be in date format, I forgot to paste that line apologies.